# How can I get `expect` to ignore Variables?

Tags: shell, powershell, expect

I need to convert a String to a Powershell Secure String.

At the moment I open an ssh connection and run there my Powershell commands. The problem is, that I can not get a Variable from expect to run in Powershell.

The command in expect:

```
send "$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force\r"
```

The error in Powershell:

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> "" = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
>
> In line: 1 character:1 + "" = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

Somebody know how I can fix this or if there is an easier solution.

Perhaps the full script helps to understand my problem.

```
#!/bin/sh
Username="benutzer"
Password="passwort"
login_user="Administrator"
ADServer="192.168.x.x"
function CreateADUser()
{
    Givenname=$1
    Surname=$2
    Email=$3
    export Givenname
    export Surname
    export Email
    Username="$Givenname.$Surname"
        /usr/bin/expect << EOD
        spawn ssh -i ~/.ssh/ADServer $login_user@$ADServer
        expect "*>"
        send "\$SecurePassword = '$Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force\r"
        expect "*>"
        send "New-ADUser -Name $Username -GivenName $Givenname -SurName $Surname  -SamAccountName $Username -EmailAddress $Email -AccountPassword  $SecurePassword\r"
        expect "*>"
        send "exit\r"
EOD
}

Email=$(dscl /LDAPv3/ldap.example.com -read /Users/$Username EMailAddress)
Email=$(echo "${Email##* }")
FirstName=$(dscl /LDAPv3/ldap.example.com -read /Users/$Username FirstName)
FirstName=$(echo "${FirstName##* }")
LastName=$(dscl /LDAPv3/ldap.example.com -read /Users/$Username LastName)
LastName=$(echo "${LastName##* }")

CreateADUser "$FirstName" "$LastName" "$Email"
```

Comment: `$SecurePassword = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force` works fine, any reason you're trying to assign the result to an empty string (`""`) instead with `"" = "Password" [...]` ?

Comment: The output of $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force should be saved in $SecurePassword. 
But the send command in expect try to use the content of the Variable and not the String. 

I need that the command is like the following in the Powershell.


$SecurePassword = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tcl's non-interpolating quotes (`set str {$vars not substituted}`) reduces the amount of escaping required. However you need one variable there substituted.

You could:

1. send it in pieces:

   ```
   send {$SecurePassword = '}
   send $Password
   send "' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force}\r"
   ```
2. use `format` which is Tcl's printf command

   ```
   send [format {$SecurePassword = '%s' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force\r} $Password]
   ```

But if you're OK with lots of backslashes, then regular double quotes are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. 
It works now. I made a small change, that I don't need to send with so many backslashes or in pieces. 
Now it's only one single String.

`send "New-ADUser -Name $Username -GivenName $Givenname -SurName $Surname -SamAccountName $Username -EmailAddress $Email -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -force) -Enabled \\\$true\r"`